# HyperSQL case insensitive delimited identifiers

Tags: sql, hsqldb

HyperSQL converts all column names to upper case when creating a table, right.
When selecting something using undelimited identifiers the identifiers are case insensitive and
`SELECT myColumn FROM myTable;`  or
`SELECT mYcOlUmN FROM myTable;`  or
`SELECT mycolumn FROM myTable;`
will work fine.

When using delimited identifiers, however, identifiers are case sensitive. So
`SELECT "MYCOLUMN" FROM myTable;`
will work but

`SELECT "myColumn" FROM myTable;`  or
`SELECT "mYcOlUmN" FROM myTable;`  or
`SELECT "mycolumn" FROM myTable;`
won't!

**<strike>All</strike> MOST of** my queries are using lower case delimited identifiers (don't ask why).
Does HyperSQL provide a way of using case-insensitive delimited identifiers OR treating non-quoted identifiers as lower-case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard SQL is not case-sensitive when you do not use quoted identifiers. When you do use them, the quoted objects are treated as case-sensitive, while unquoted names are treated as uppercase.

You can rename all your columns to their lowercase version.

```
ALTER TABLE MYTABLE ALTER COLUMN MYCOLUMN RENAME TO "mycolumn"
```

You can do this programatically (in Java) by selecting all table + column names in the PUBLIC schema and executing the rename statement for each column.

Comment: Ups.. I've mislead you! MOST of my queries are using lower case quoted identifiers! In your example all further select queries should use quoted identifiers since non-quoted ones are treated as uppercase!

Comment: Usage must be consistent and follow the rules. There is no other way.